# Click flag to highlight issue

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, font-awesome

I have a table that lists various fields from a customer database.  I'd like to add a new column with a grey flag (indicates no issues) If the user clicks the flag I'd like the flag to turn red (indicates there is an issue)

I'm using MVC, Angularjs and Font Awesome.

Could someone point me in the best direction please?

```html
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Florence.Authentication;
using Florence.Data;
using Florence.Website.Models;
using Florence.Website.Models.Job;

namespace Florence.Website.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    
    /// </summary>
    public class JobController : Controller
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Search jobs
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Job list</returns>
        [AuthorizationFilter(PermissionList = "CanListJobs")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("~/views/job/index.cshtml");
        }

[AuthorizationFilter(PermissionList = "CanViewJobs", AllowLocalRequests = true)]
        public ActionResult PdfView(int id)
        {
            using (var context = new FlorenceContext())
            {
                var job = context.Jobs
                    .Include(c => c.Customer)
                    .Include(c => c.Customer.Address)
                    .First(c => c.Id == id);

                if (!HttpContext.Request.IsLocal && job.BelongsToCompanyId != DataBag.LoggedOnCompany.Id)
                {
                    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                }

                return View("~/views/job/pdf/view.cshtml", job);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your table structure, but you need to create either a new property in your array, for each row, or a new array with the same length as the original one. Then simply add a new column and detect any changes to that new property/array.

Here is a simple demo (click on text *Icon* to change the flag):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [
    {"ID":12345,"Details":"ABC"},
    {"ID":23456,"Details":"BCD"},
    {"ID":34567,"Details":"CDE"},
    {"ID":45678,"Details":"DEF"}
  ];

  // a new array of the same length (a `map` of it)
  $scope.flags = $scope.array.map(function(_){return false;});

  $scope.submit = function(){
    console.log($scope.flags); // (extra)
  }
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <form ng-submit="submit()">
      <table>

        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in array[0]">
            {{key}}
          </th>
          <th>
            Flag
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="data in array">
          <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">
            {{value}}
          </td>
          <td>
            <span ng-click="flags[$index] = !flags[$index]">
            <i ng-class="{'red':flags[$index]}">Icon</i>
          </span>
          </td>
        </tr>

      </table>

      <!-- (extra) -->
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, most appreciated.  Unfortunately I'm a little unsure how to add the code section into my controller.  I understand the new column in the table.  I've added my controller code to my original comment.  Many thanks